# I have missing data in my pandas dataframe. How can I tell python not to include it in a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file `mart_export.txt` full of two different types of keys that looks like this

```
Gene stable ID  RefSeq match transcript
ENSG00000243959 
ENSG00000206698 
ENSG00000265684 
ENSG00000251990 
ENSG00000241552 
ENSG00000050767 NM_173465.4
```

As you can see, most of the right column doesn't have any data, but I am trying to build a new pandas dataframe out of just the indices that have values for both columns. Here is my script so far

```
#Put the biomart export in a pandas dataframe
mart = pd.read_csv("mart_export.txt", delimiter="\t")

#Create new list of records with Gene Stable Id and RefSeq numbers
d = {'Gene Stable ID': [], 'RefSeq ID': []}
for i in mart:
    if mart['RefSeq match transcript'] != NaN:
        d['Gene Stable ID'].append(mart['Gene stable ID'])
        d['RefSeq ID'].append(mart['RefSeq match transcript'])
```

In Spyder, the values in the second column that are blank are labeled NaN, but when I try to use this value in my code, I get an error in python that says NaN is not defined. How can I specify to python what a blank looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop rows or columns using [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) method of pandas `DataFrame`.

In your case, it would be:

```
mart.dropna(axis="rows", inplace=True)
```

You can drop columns containing `NaN`s, specify `how` argument and so on, check the docs linked above.

Answer (score 0):

To detect `NaN`, you may use `pd.isna` or `pd.isnull`.

However, `mart` is DataFrame, so `mart['RefSeq match transcript']` is a column.

`mart['RefSeq match transcript'] == something` will return a series.

Therefore, condition `'if mart['RefSeq match transcript'] == something'` will always return errors no matter what value you tried to compare.

You either need to `dropna` as shown in other answers or filter out `nan` such as belows:

```
mart_noNaN = mart[~mart['RefSeq match transcript'].isna()]
```

notice the `'~'`  negation in front of `mart.